# concatenating a string and then executing the string statement using the concatenated string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have made many unique formulas using Concatenate. i.e. `=concatenate(lookupSheet$b$2,row(),if(a3>50,lookupSheet$h$2,row(),....)` eventually generating strings that are unique Hlookups for differing data sets.

When I paste the hlookup strings to another column, Excel treats it as text until I place the cursor in the Function field and press enter, then it treats it as the formula.  How can I perform this conversion on the entire pasted column at one time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One way:**

Double click on any formula cell, As you said it will convert you to a formula, then copy it ,paste using paste special the format on entire cells which contain the same formula and then hit  <kbd>enter</kbd> , you formula will converted to its values returned.

[image]

**Note:** In case an apostrophe there then do this, to remove apostrophe ( this showing because of lotus compatibility), Go to File > Options > Advanced tab > Scroll down to Lotus Compatibility > Uncheck “Transitional navigation keys” box > Click OK button and then do the excerise which is mentioned above.

**Another way:**

Step 1: Select the data using mouse or keyboard

Step 2: Go to Data Tab > Data Tools group > Text to column button

Step 3: Once the dialogue box appears. Do nothing and click Finish button.

**Note however that this does not work with Text**

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Unfortunately, I've still thousands of individual formulas thanks to each line having a unique min()  as my first concatenate values are '=Hlookup(min(k and row().  :/

Comment: You have to paste the format of the cell(i hope you got this) only so I don't see why its not working even if the formulas are different.

Comment: :)  yep I got it and I agree that logically it should work; unfortunately its not.  I'm beginning to think its finally time to learn some VBA grammar...

Comment: I think there is an apostrophe here, to remove this( this showing because of lotus compatibilty), Go to File > Options > Advanced tab > Scroll down to Lotus Compatibility > Uncheck “Transitional navigation keys” box > Click OK button and Try the excercise which i have mentioned

Comment: Maybe...  I've checked options and no lotus compatibility settings are checked.   My first static value that is concatenated is **'=hlookup(min(k**     Could that leading apostrophe in that cell be my culprit?

Comment: Just uncheck that and then do the process as suggested in the answer. see if this works

Answer (score 0):

Put it inside `INDIRECT` function. `INDIRECT(expression)` evaluates the expression.

Not for your case but one important note about `INDIRECT` function: You can not see trace dependencies of indirect calls. You can see only direct references.

Comment: I had tried indirect(pasted concatenated value) receiving only a #REF!   I many be using indirect incorrectly.  I've never attempted to use it before today.

Comment: Does your concatenated value includes `=` sign at the beginning?

Comment: @Revman No need to paste your code inside indirect. Let your expression be in a cell(ie. A5). Then in another cell write `=INDIRECT(A5)`.

Comment: I should have typed 'cell reference containing concatenated value'  I also tried 'cell reference containing concatenation formula' each to the same effect.